# Key value to be added in nested array

Tags: json, jq

This is my json which i am trying to parse using jq

```
{
    "orgs": {
        "org1": [{
                "space": "landscape2",
                "tag": "landscape2",
                "manager": {
                    "destination": "destination1"
                }},
            {
                "space": "landscape3",
                "tag": "landscape3",
                "manager": {
                    "destination1": "approuter",
                    "destination2": "approuter2"
                }},
            {
                "space": "landscape4",
                "app": "",
                "l_port_increment": 25,
                "host": "",
                "port": ""
            }],
        "org2": [
        {
                "space": "landscape1",
                "app": "ain-hana-chisel-cs",
                "l_port_increment": 13,
                "host": "10.03.76.234",
                "port": "30044"
            },
            {
                "space": "landscape3",
                "tag": "landscape3",                
                "manager1": {
                    "destination5": "service-v2",
                    "destination6": "service-v2"
                },
                "manager": {
                    "destination": "destination1"
                },
                "l_port_increment": 25,
                "host": "",
                "port": ""
            }   ]       }    }
```

I am looking for an output as below where tag should be one of the filter.

```
{
  "orgs: "org1",
  "space": "landscape3",
  "tag": "landscape3",
  "manager": {
    "destination1": "approuter",
    "destination2": "approuter2"
  }
}
{
  "orgs": "org2",
  "space": "landscape3",
  "tag": "landscape3",
  "manager1": {
    "destination5": "service-v2",
    "destination6": "service-v2"
  },
  "manager": {
    "destination": "destination1"
  },
  "l_port_increment": 25,
  "host": "",
  "port": ""
}
```

Using this code, I can achieve the result partially, however unable to get the orgs details.
    .orgs[] | .[ ] | select(."tag"=="landscape3")  | select (."manager")

My actual output is as below. How to do it by using jq? I have tried several ways but unable tot get the desired output

```
 {
  "space": "landscape3",
  "tag": "landscape3",
  "manager": {
    "destination1": "approuter",
    "destination2": "approuter2"
  }
}
{
  "space": "landscape3",
  "tag": "landscape3",
  "manager1": {
    "destination5": "service-v2",
    "destination6": "service-v2"
  },
  "manager": {
    "destination": "destination1"
  },
  "l_port_increment": 25,
  "host": "",
  "port": ""
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your description of the task is not much clear, but I guess you're looking for something like this:

```
.orgs
| keys_unsorted[] as $k
| {orgs:$k} + first(.[$k][] | select(has("manager") and .tag == "landscape3"))
```

For each key in `orgs`, selects the objects which have `manager` as key and `tag: landscape` key-value pair from corresponding array, adds `orgs: <key>` to the first and outputs the resulting object. If multiple objects are selected, the rest except the first one is omitted.

Comment: Thanks. That works like wonder. Is there a possibility to exclude manager1 in the output and show the remaining  as it is?

Comment: Using `.orgs
| keys_unsorted[] as $k
| {orgs:$k} + first(.[$k][] | select(has("manager") and .tag == "landscape3"))
|  {orgs: .orgs, space: .space, tag:.tag, manager:.manager} `    
helped. Thanks again.